# Combining st_snaptogrid with st_centroid and group by using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, snapping, centroids, postgis-2.3

I have a table of devices, each of them has a field 'location' that is a postGis geometry(Point,4326)

I need to operate a GROUP BY based of the placement on a grid, I'd use [ST_SnapToGrid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) and then I need to get the [ST_Centroid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html) on each set of points in the cell.

I can correctly group by grid:

```
SELECT count(*) as count, 
   st_astext(ST_SnapToGrid(location, 50)) as grid 
FROM device_device GROUP BY grid;
 count |       grid       
-------+------------------
  3864 | POINT(0 0)
  1462 | POINT(0 -100)
  1377 | POINT(0 100)
```

and I can get the centroid out of many points:

```
testgis=# SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(
            ST_Collect( ARRAY(SELECT location FROM device_device) )));
                   st_astext                   
-----------------------------------------------
 POINT(-0.281948442456614 0.00443529565569083)
(1 riga)
```

I cannot understand how to mix the 2 and calculate the centroid *for each* cell:

```
testgis=# select count(*) as count, 
  st_astext(ST_SnapToGrid(location, 50)) as grid, 
  st_astext(ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(ARRAY(location)))) 
FROM device_device group by grid;
ERRORE:  errore di sintassi a o presso "location"
RIGA 1: ...) as grid, st_astext(ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(ARRAY(location))...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with the `COUNT(*)`, the `SELECT` can utilize (almost) every other aggregate function, keeping the reference to the grouped rows defined by the `GROUP BY`.

Not directly obvious: in your first query you implicitly `GROUP BY ST_SnapToGrid(...)` already, by using the column expression alias `grid`.

With that in mind, just run this very similar query:

```
SELECT  ST_Centroid( ST_Collect( location ) ) AS geom
FROM    device_device
GROUP BY
        ST_SnapToGrid( location, 50 )
;
```

Comment: Thanks! so my mistake was to add ARRAY, that I used w/o really understanding...